# Recursão em Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Estou a tentar fazer uma função recursiva em Python que não me está a atribuir os resultados corretos e quando tento alterá-la acontece sempre stack overflow. O meu código é este:

```
def sublistas(lista):
i=0
if not isinstance(lista,list):
    return 0
elif type(lista[i])==list:
    return sublistas(lista[i])+(1)
else:
    return 0
```

Alguém é capaz de me ajudar a perceber o que está errado aqui ?

Comment: Por favor explique o que seu código deveria fazer, não da para dizer o que está errado se você sem saber qual o objetivo do algoritmo. Batendo o olho  até da para supor que seja um contador recursivo de sublistas dentro da lista original, mas é suposição, edite sua pergunta e deixe ela mais clara.

Answer (score 1):

Tem muita coisa errada, vamos lá:

1. Pelo visto, vc quer identificar se um lista, contenha sublistas. Na linha 3, o seu `if` apenas troca o valor booleano e não gera uma condição, o returno sempre será `0`(Zero)
2. `elif` só pesquisa a sublista no primeiro item da lista.

E melhor vc repensar o seu programa.